Unable to locate package epstopdf
I am unable to install epstopdf after moving to Ubuntu 24.04 from 23.10. Any solutions?
Update:
I tried : sudo apt install epstopdf
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package epstopdf
Update2 :
The issue got resolved with "sudo apt install texlive-full". It seems epstopdf is with texlive installation.

you don't say what research you have done but this Stack Exchange post might be related.

How did you try to install epstopdf? What was the error message? Please update the question and add more details.

Results of epstopdf in Ubuntu 24.04:
Command 'epstopdf' not found, but can be installed with:
sudo apt install texlive-font-utils

Run sudo apt install texlive-font-utils as suggested to install epstopdf in Ubuntu 24.04. By default, epstopdf converts the input PostScript file to PDF, using Ghostscript.

Thanks, this solved the problem. I installed sudo apt install texlive-full and got epstopdf with it.

texlive usually prompts you to install a missing package when you need one to run your LaTeX program, and usually the missing package can be installed from the default Ubuntu repositories.
